# Loop through filenames and delete last n charaters

Tags: bash

I have many `fq.gz` files in a directory and I want to loop through each filename, delete the last 8 characters and print this to a sample name text file 
eg.

```
984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--R1.fq.gz
984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--R2.fq.gz
```

will become:

```
984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--  
984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--
```

At the moment I have a `bash` script to put each filename into an array and then print the array to a `sample.txt` file. I have then tried to `mv` the filename to the new desired filename:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a FILELIST
for f in *.gz; do
    #FILELIST[length_of_FILELIST + 1]=filename
    FILELIST[${#FILELIST[@]}+1]=$(echo "$f");
done
printf '%s\n' "${FILELIST[@]:1:10}" > sample.txt

sample_info=sample.txt

sample_files=($(cut -f 1 "$sample_info"))
for file in "${sample_files[@]}"
do
mv  "$file" "${file::(-8)}"
echo $file
done
```

But the script isn't removing any characters. Can you help?

Comment: BTW, to fill an array with filenames, you can do `arr=(*.gz)`. And to append, you can do `arr+=(filename)`.

Comment: Does the file names always have `--R` pattern in them ?

Answer (score 2):

*to loop through each filename, delete the last 8 characters and print this to a sample name*, would this work for you:

```
for i in *fq.gz
do
  echo ${i:0:-8}
done
```

Comment: This works for `GNU bash >= 4.2`. In `4.1` you would get a `-bash: -8: substring expression < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Using substring removal, [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).  Assuming you want exactly `8` characters out from the end:

```
for n in *.fq.gz
do
   echo "${n%%??.fq.gz}"
done
```

For a test,

```
$ n="984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--R1.fq.gz"
$ echo "${n%%??.fq.gz}"
984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--
```

OR

```
$ echo "${n%%????????}"
984674-TAATGAGC-GCTGTAGA--
```